# Will the Domain SMTP IP been blacklisted cause the Email Contains the Domain not deliver?

Tags: email, smtp, mx-record, blacklist

One of my domain is using https://www.cloudns.net/ as DNS server, they also offer email forward, so I need to setup my MX to

```
5   mailforward1.cloudns.net
10 mailforward2.cloudns.net
```

to use the email forwarding.

Everything is perfect except the `mailforward1.cloudns.net` and 2 as well, are heavily listed in many popular blacklist. I can understand that since they just forward email and not care about who sent it or what content it is, so it will have bad reputation. And amazingly, the blacklist of the mentioned domain/IP does not effect I receive the forward emails.

What I wanna ask here, is not I will use these smtp server to send email (I cannot anyway, since they are not for public to send email).

My question is: **for the emails I sent, which contains the domain that has above smtp server as MX, will the blacklist of the MX servers cause my email has higher spam score or cause no-delivery.**

If answer is yes, the domain in the email will effect the delivery, then what kind of remedy do you suggest except not use the email forwarding service.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, someone getting mail from an SMTP relay will only check that relay's reputation against their relay blacklist - the reputation of systems present in the `MX` records for that domain should not impact the spam score.  So, you should be fine.

However, that's not a guarantee - someone receiving a message can build a spam score however they'd like, and I've seen crazier ideas implemented in SMTP filters.

Comment: What about a normal user get an email contains the domain which using a "spam relay", will this indicates the domain in trouble, and the email should be a spam?

Comment: @EricYin I don't think so. If I'm getting a message from someone, and their relay for the return mail is on a blacklist, that's they're business; I'm not getting a message from a blacklisted server, so I'm happy.